# Generating function for amount of words, only using letters A,B and C, without two or more successive A's.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

Question in the title; I kinda feel helpless about that one.

Comment: Every word of length $n+2$ is either a word of length $n+1$ followed by a $B$ or $C$, or a word of length $n$ followed by by either pair $BA$ or $CA.$ So your have $a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}+2a_{n},$ and you just need to figure out $a_0$ and $a_1.$

Comment: "Question in the title" is never the best way to post Questions.  The body of the Question allows you to give substantial context for the problem to be solved (a detailed setup. a precise goal, and context for why a "generating function" solution is required, if it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will find a linear recurrence relation for the number of words. Finding a generating function for such relations are straightforward.
Let $a_n$ be the number of words with length $n$. For $n>=2,$ consider words of length $n$. If the last letter is A, then the second last letter must be B or C, and the first $n-2$ letters can be any word that satisfies the condition. So there are $2a_{n-2}$ such words. If the last letter is B or C, then the first $n-1$ letters can be any word that satisfies the condition. So there are $2a_{n-1}$ such words. Thus our recurrence relation is 
$$a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}.$$
We also have $a_0=1$ (the empty word) and $a_1=3$.
We finally find the generating function.
If $f(x)$ is the generating function, then we have 
$$2xf(x) + 2x^2f(x) = f(x)-x-1$$
since the coefficient for $x^n$ on the LHS is $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}$ except for the coefficients of 1 and x, which both fall one short.
So the generating function is
$$f(x) = \frac{x+1}{1-2x-2x^2}.$$